# Solve for the charge on a discharging capacitor in an RC circuit using Laplace Transforms. (5.3-61)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, applications

Please check my work. I need to solve the following problem but my answer varies from that of the book by a factor of $C$ for capacitance. A print screen of the problem is given below.

**Problem to solve**:

[image]

**My setup**:

The differential equation for the charge on the capacitor is...

$$R\cdot q'+\frac{1}{C}\cdot q=0$$

with initial condition $q(0)=v_0$.

**My solution**

$$\mathcal{L}\{q'(t)\}=sQ-v_0$$

$$(sQ-v_0)+\frac{1}{RC}\cdot Q=0$$

$$Q(s+\frac{1}{RC})=v_0$$

$$Q=\frac{v_0}{s+\frac{1}{RC}}$$

**My answer**:

$$q(t)=v_0e^{-\frac{1}{RC}\cdot t}$$

**Answer in text**:

$$q(t)=Cv_0e^{-\frac{1}{RC}\cdot t}$$

Where did that $C$ come from? Was my setup wrong?

Comment: I uploaded the image earlier and it showed but then for some reason it dropped it. Anyway the image is back up now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more physics but look the answer is that your answer is correct if you used the initial condition $q(0)=q_0$.

$Cv_0=q_0$: this is the definition of capaciatance.

The initial *voltage* is $v_0$ but you'd call the initial charge by $q_0$... or initial charge

$$q_0=CV_0.$$

Comment: Yes we know that capacitance C is known. I should have checked my units. Charge is in coulombs, electromotive potential is in volts, and capacitance is in farads. You solved it. Thank you.

Comment: I did. Check again.